# Tablecell click short delay

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview, tablecell

When I click on table cell, there's a short delay of 1-2 second before it loads the next view. I've seen some apps that show an activity indicator during that time and that's what I'd like to do. I've added one like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
  spinner.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,200,200);
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.accessoryView = spinner;
  [spinner startAnimating];
  [spinner release];

  VenueViewController *vviewcontroller = [[VenueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VenueViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vviewcontroller animated:YES];
  [vviewcontroller release];
  vviewcontroller = nil;}
```

however this also appears with a delay, and just before the next view is showing. It seems the app freezes for 1-2 seconds after clicking on the table cell so it doesn't even show the activity indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the secret is that you should call load method using a performSelector method. Another tip is hiding or showing the activity so it won't consume time this operation.

So this could be a pseudocode of that

Inside your ViewController class definition:

```
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spin;  // created in view and hidden
```

In your implementation...

```
-(void) load{ // your code
  VenueViewController *vviewcontroller = [[VenueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VenueViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vviewcontroller animated:YES];
  [vviewcontroller release];
  vviewcontroller = nil;

  spin.hidden=YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  spinner.hidden=NO;

  [self performSelector:@selector(load) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Because it is queued for execution in the next loop cycle   more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html   and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject

Comment: Thanks. The performSelector didn't make any difference, but I'm testing on iPad 1, I guess the delay won't be much of an issue in newer iPads. One last question, how can I move the spinner inside the table cells that's been clicked. Right now I have it centred on stage.

Comment: Just solved it. Just add `[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] addSubview:spin];` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Thanks for helping